# Drupal Book Navigation Link Change

Tags: 7, nodes

I am trying to fix something that was done from a previous developer who used the Books Module in Drupal 7. I can't figure out how to change the link to return to the parent "chapter" as seen below. The link is wrong and I just need to change it. I'm just not sure where that info is stored.

How is that menu created? I've already looked and he did not use the Book Navigation Block.

[image]

Update: I think I found a template file that contains the code, but I'm still not sure how to alter it or fix this link:

```
<?php print l('‹ All Chapters in this Program', drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $parent_node->nid), array('class' => 'font_15')); ?>
```

Comment: Is there still a question?

Comment: Yes. I still don't know where to change the link or where it is getting the wrong link info from.